# Turtle - incorrect coordinates with setworldcoordinates when embedded in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wanted to make the turtle go to a certain coordinate on a map and I got it working when I set it up as a standalone
import turtle

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(720, 360)
screen.bgpic('map.gif')
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)

quake = turtle.Turtle()
quake.color("red")
quake.turtlesize(1)
quake.shape("circle")

quake.penup()
quake.goto(-178.4746, -17.9625)
quake.stamp()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

This is what the correct location is supposed to be:
[image: correct location]

However, when I tried to have the turtle screen embedded on tkinter, the coordinates were off.

```
import turtle
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(width = 720, height = 800)

def geoviz():
    quake.goto(-178.4746, -17.9625)
    quake.stamp()

button = Button(window, text="Compute Map", command= geoviz)
button.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 720, height = 360)
canvas.pack()

quake = RawTurtle(canvas)
quake.shape("circle")
quake.color("red")

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgpic('map.gif')
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)

mainloop()
```

This is where the turtle stamp is instead, which is way off from the correct location:
[image: wrong location]

Comment: I'd really suggest not using both of them. `turtle` is made in `tkinter` but AFAIK/have heard it is kinda meant for learning, so... Also that `turtle` and `tkinter` use different coordinate systems so you would have to adjust that too, which actually may be the cause of the problem, also you kinda need to press that button

Comment: anyways, it does everything correctly, if you reduce the canvas width to 360, then you will see that it goes to near the edge which is expected

Comment: reducing the canvas width will solve nothing because what i'm looking for is putting the the stamp in the correct position in relation to the map, not the canvas.

Comment: could you please provide the image used in your code?

Comment: here it is: https://imgur.com/brZjzpA

Comment: apparently you need to multiply coordinates you want to go to by `screen.xscale` and `screen.yscale` (not necessary here because it is 1) so it should be `quake.goto(-178.4746 * screen.xscale, -17.9625)`, when you use `turtle.Turtle` it does this internally

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is, if you want to use your *user defined coords* then you need to use the **screen** as well:

```
quake = RawTurtle(screen)
```

will solve your issue.

```
def __init__(self, cv):
        self.cv = cv
        if isinstance(cv, ScrolledCanvas):
            w = self.cv.canvwidth
            h = self.cv.canvheight
        else:  # expected: ordinary TK.Canvas
            w = int(self.cv.cget("width"))
            h = int(self.cv.cget("height"))
            self.cv.config(scrollregion = (-w//2, -h//2, w//2, h//2 ))
        self.canvwidth = w
        self.canvheight = h
        self.xscale = self.yscale = 1.0
```

[The coordinatesytem is given by the cv](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/122ca4d73faba279a579aa2011fa34661ce537a2/Lib/turtle.py#L480), if you wont work with canvas coordinates and use screencoordinates, you will need to pass the right argument. Full code:

```
import turtle
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(width = 720, height = 800)

def geoviz():
    quake.goto(-178.4746, -17.9625)
    quake.stamp()

button = Button(window, text="Compute Map", command= geoviz)
button.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 720, height = 360)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgpic('map.gif')
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)

quake = RawTurtle(screen)
quake.shape("circle")
quake.color("red")

mainloop()
```